# List.js Dropdown Filter - How to reset to initial state?

Tags: jquery, html, list.js

I have the dropdown filter working properly but I'd like to offer an All value that refreshes the list items and shows the initial state (all list items being visible).

I have a button that does this onClick:

```
$('#filter-clear').click(function() {
  featureList.filter();
  return false;
});
```

The if statement in the dropdown code below isn't working as expected.
Basically, if the selection value is ALL I want to run the same function that the filter-clear button runs (showing all items). Otherwise return the items with the selected value.

Here's a codepen of the dropdown working without the below if statement: https://codepen.io/nolaandy/pen/Zryaoq

My Dropdown Code:

```
$('#positionChange').change(function () {
var selection = this.value; 
var option=document.getElementById('positionChange').value;
console.log(selection);console.log(option);

featureList.filter(function (item) {
  if (selection='ALL') {
      featureList.filter();
      } else {
return (item.values().playerPosition == selection);
}
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$('#positionChange').change(function () {
var selection = this.value; 
var option=document.getElementById('positionChange').value;
console.log(selection);console.log(option);
if(selection != 'ALL')
    featureList.filter();
else
    featureList.filter(function (item) {
        return (item.values().playerPosition == selection);
    });

});
```

it is not good to have if/else inside the function filter is better to do it out side.